# How to reload the first test case if it fails in cypress

Tags: javascript, testing, cypress, integration-testing, e2e-testing

Every feature test case starts with landing page testing in cypress.

We are witnessing failures here because of network connectivity issues.

```
it('should load home page', () => {
    cy.waitUntil(() =>
      cy.contains('Home', { timeout: 500000 }).should('exist')
    );
  });
```

So, is there a way to reload this test case if it fails once or twice and avoid recursion?

I suspect retries will work here, if so how can we configure it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Test Retries](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/test-retries). You can add it to Test Suite Level, Test Case level or globally as well. The test will be re-triggered in case of failures.

`runMode` works for headless. `openMode` for test runner. You can add both of them followed by how many times you want to retry them. So `2` means, once after the test failed, the test will be re-executed 2 times until the test passes, So if the test passes in the first re-execution, the second re-execution will not happen.

```js
it(
  'should load home page',
  {
    retries: {
      runMode: 2,
      openMode: 1,
    },
  },
  () => {
    cy.waitUntil(() => cy.contains('Home', {timeout: 500000}).should('exist'))
  }
)
```

Comment: Thanks, i was looking at this in documentation. OpenMode refers to opening the browser. Pipeline tests run in head less mode, does this work?

Comment: Yes `runMode` works for headless. `openMode`  for test runner. You can add both of them. Followed by how many times you want to retry them. So 2 means, once after failed, the retry will happen 2 times, meaning total 3 executions will be done.